# How to turn off warnings while debugging in VS Code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm debugging a PHP app in VS Code using XDebug(`PHP Debug` extension) and getting errors like:

[image: VS Code PHP debugging error]

I understand what the problem is and how to fix it, but the solution is so huge, that fixing such an errors is something I can't do at the moment.

I want to start using VS Code for PHP development. I was using Visual Studio with "PHP Tools for Visual Studio" and didn't have this problem.

In the first script which is loaded when the request occurs, I have `error_reporting(E_ALL^E_WARNING^E_NOTICE);`, which should suppress such an errors. But it seems that the VS Code debugger ignores it. I didn't find any setting for `PHP Debug` which could help me with this.

Is there any way how to tell VS Code Debugger to ignore/not display such errors?

Comment: That's for the PHP page output, not VS codem, trying messing in here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: That's what I actually thought, but need to confirm. I'm diging through the XDebug configuration and looking for appropriate settings. Will answer my Q once sorted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is possible to set where debugger stops in "Debug / Breakpoints" panel or VS Code:

[image]